# Unable to create new app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

My terminal is showing this at the start of the command line:

> **subalcharla@subal-charlas-macbook ~ $**

And as a consequence when try to create a new app using rails with the command:

**`subalcharla@subal-charlas-macbook ~ $ rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit`**

The app that appears in **Finder** in my Mac 10.5.8 is named **new** instead of **sample_app**. Also, --skip-test-unit does not seem to be working.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an older version of rails installed to check the version in you terminal type

```
rails -v
```

if the version is < 3.0, update rails to 3.2

```
gem install rails -v 3.2
```

Comment: I had all the version of ruby (1.9.3), rails (3.2.3) and rvm. For some strange reason, rvm no longer exists and ruby and rails have gone back to their original versions, i.e. 1.8.6 and 1.2.6 respectively. Any clue why this would have happened or how can get my stuff back without the trouble of installing rvm, ruby and rails?

Comment: it looks like your rvm is not loading, try source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm and than rvm use 1.9.3 --default